# How to split code string properly

Tags: python, string, syntax

I am trying to write a basic lexical analyzer for Java in Python. The problem I am facing right now is splitting a line of string into words/tokens.

**Example:**

```
if (x < 3)
{
    x = 3;
}
else
{
    x = 0;
}
```

I want this to return a list like this:

```
["if", "(", "x", "<", "3", ")", ...
```

But my code is returning

```
["if", "(x", "<", "3)"]
```

**My Code:**

```
for line in code.readlines():
    for word in line.split():
        print word
```

I searched for a solution but only found solutions using regular expressions, is there a way to do this without regular expressions? Because I have no idea how to use them and I do not have enough time right now to learn it...

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: yes but that's Java code and Java allows this: `if (x>3){}`

Comment: At the very least, you need to have a set of valid syntactical tokens for your language and match against them. Otherwise, you'll get nowhere with this approach.

Comment: Take a look at the [shlex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) module.

Comment: @Shashank I have a complete list of valid syntactical tokens I am just having the problem here, if I am able to split the line as I want to then I will be able to check each word/token against the set of tokens that I have defined. The code above is just a small portion of my code...

Comment: It's almost impossible just using Python regex alone to lex the text in Java syntax.  Something like the `pyparsing` library may be what you need.

Comment: @PM2Ring I used the `shlex.split()` and now the only problem is `;` is not being splitted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python string `.split()` function, split string that separated by white space by default and return a list that contains any mixed characters without spaces. my simple suggest is that you replace sign characters by new two side spaces sign before using `.split()` function:

```
for line in code.readlines():
    for sign in '({[<+-=*/%;>]})':
        line = line.replace(sign, ' %s ' % sign)
    for word in line.split():
        print word
```

Comment: `{[<+-=*/%>;]}` I just included the semi-colon and this works... Thanks

Comment: I think that will fail on if(x == 3). Because it will split the equality operator == into two assignment operators = =.  Is that what you want?

Comment: this code work correct, but in later time programmer must check that if two special signs similar `==`, `>=`, '<=` find in list(similar [..., '=', '=', ...]) join both characters.